# how to trigger an event when an event has ended

Tags: actionscript-3

I dont know if what i want is best described with the Title of this question, but Its the shortest way to explain what I want to accomplish.

So Im trying to figure out how to make a _circle to move from one corner to the next corner of an Object (that it is in), but that movement (of the _circle )has to start only when the _box Object (the one that the _circle is in), has stopped moving i.e it is in the center of the stage.
And also at the very same second the _box is goingUp, the _circle to stop moving and stay in the position it is in until i click the _button again.

I have only the logic for the moving of the _box element. (and even that logic is too ugly coded/ not that elegant)

```
private var _myBox:Sprite = new Sprite();
    private var _myCircle:Sprite = new Sprite();
    private var _myButton:Sprite = new Sprite();

    public function Test2()
    {
        addChild(_myBox);
        _myBox.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF);
        _myBox.graphics.drawRect(0,0,300,100);
        _myBox.graphics.endFill();
        _myBox.x = stage.stageWidth * 0.5 - _myBox.width * 0.5 ;
        _myBox.y = 0 - _myBox.height;

        _myBox.addChild(_myCircle);
        _myCircle.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
        _myCircle.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,20);
        _myCircle.graphics.endFill();
        _myCircle.x = 0 + _myCircle.width * 0.5;
        _myCircle.y = _myCircle.height * 0.5 + _myCircle.height * 0.5;

        addChild(_myButton);
        _myButton.graphics.beginFill(0xAFAFAF);
        _myButton.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
        _myButton.graphics.endFill();
        _myButton.x = 400
        _myButton.y = 300
        _myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

        var moveBoxDown:Timer = new Timer( 1000, 1 );
        moveBoxDown.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, goingDown);
        moveBoxDown.start();
    }

    function goingDown(ev:TimerEvent):void
    {
        TweenLite.to( _myBox, 0.5 , {y: stage.stageHeight/2-_myBox.height/2 } );
    }

    private function onClick(ev:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var moveBoxUp:Timer = new Timer( 1000, 1 );
        moveBoxUp.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, goingUp);
        moveBoxUp.start();
    }

    function goingUp(ev:TimerEvent):void
    {
        TweenLite.to( _myBox, 0.5 , {y: 0 - _myBox.height } );
    }
```

So any help in my issue ? or making the code more eye pleasing.Would be very tankful.

Comment: I seem to remember that tweenlite has an oncomplete handler. You could use this to kick off the circle once the square has arrived at it's first position and then again for the circle. That way you could also rid yourself of the Timers.

Comment: I've just had a look. delayedCall is something slightly different. onComplete is a parameter that's passed to a tween, the same way you've passed x and y parameters i.e. TweenLite.to(mc, 1, {x:100, onComplete:myFunction}); and if you need to pass the function parameters you can : TweenLite.to(mc, 1, {x:100, onComplete:myFunction, onCompleteParams:["param1", 2]}); This will carry out myFunction once the tween has finished :)

Comment: Have a look here under special properties http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/_tweenmax.html

Comment: well Ive just tried several things but nothing works.I removed the timer events and just added this line of code ** TweenMax.to(_myBox, 2, {y:100, onComplete:move_Circle(), onCompleteParams:[ 100, 300]} )** but its not waiting the _box to get to the center of the stage.It just executes (the circle moves) as the _box moves to the center.I did read the **to** function description but there was only as little as this (apart from the usual) **It can also contain special properties like "onComplete", "ease", "delay", etc.**, hasnt got a example, and what i tried .... i failed :D

Comment: And when I try to do this **function move_Circle(param1:int , param2:int):void** it is giving me an error **1136: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 2.**?why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function goingDown(ev:TimerEvent):void
{
    TweenLite.to( _myBox, 0.5 , {y: stage.stageHeight/2-_myBox.height/2, onComplete:onTweenComplete } );
}

function onTweenComplete(ev:Event = null)
{
    //Do whatever after the tween has ended
}
```